# .bashrc - Shortening "Rails S -b $IP -p $PORT"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash

I am using `cloud9`, so to run the server I have to type in the command `Rails S -b $IP -p $PORT`.  How can I shorten it to `Rails S` using `.bashrc`?

Thanks!

Comment: `alias rs="rails s -b $IP -p $PORT"`.

Answer (score 1):

OK, you can do this on `cloud9` using `alias` in `.bash_aliases` file, but you can't exactly `Rails S` because `alias` naming convention not supported `space` in a variable.

On your `cloud9` `.bash_aliases` file use like below

```
alias RailsS="rails s -b $IP -p $PORT"
or
alias Rails_S="rails s -b $IP -p $PORT"
or
alias rails_s="rails s -b $IP -p $PORT"
or
alias rs="rails s -b $IP -p $PORT"
or
alias rails_server="rails s -b $IP -p $PORT"
or what do you want
```

After that you can restart your `cloud9` workspace otherwise the `.bash_aliases` won't be recognized as updated. That's it.

Now use which variable you have defined to your `.bash_aliases` file. If you have used this `alias rs="rails s -b $IP -p $PORT"` then you can write the command `rs` and hit enter, see the below

```
$ rs
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.1.4 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.11.2 (ruby 2.3.4-p301), codename: Love Song
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:8080
Use Ctrl-C to stop
Started GET "/" for 114.31.20.44 at 2018-03-18 10:10:02 +0000
```

Done! :)

---

Now question is where you will find this `.bash_aliases` file, Right?

Don't worry! this so much easy to find this.

You will find it on the left side `Workspace->Setting Icon->Show Hidden Files`, You can click on the left side upper right settings icon click it then it will show a list then you can click `Show Hidden Files`

See the attached images

[image]

[image]

Click to pollup this.

Hope it helps.